# Java command line option using @ symbol

Tags: java

When invoking the 'java' process, I'm almost certain there is a way to have Java expand the contents of a file into a set of additional command-line arguments using the "@" symbol.

Something like:

java @myfile -cp foo -Dbar=baz com.mydomain.MyApp

And then the contents of "myfile" will be used as additional parameters.

It doesn't seem to work, but I'm certain that something very similar *used* to work.  I've searched high and low but can't find anything on the InterNETs to help.  Its driving me nuts!  Someone please refresh my memory or lock me up.

Comment: What operating system are you using? This is easy to do in Unix.

Comment: For the record, this was added to the Java launcher (`java`/`javaw`) with Java SE 9.  Prior to that release, only the compiler supported it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably the compiler you're thinking of:

```
javac [ options ] [ sourcefiles ] [ classes ] [ @argfiles ]
```

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Comment: Since Java 9, it is also supported on `java`.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anything like that in any JVM I've used.

Are you sure it wasn't a specific Java application, e.g. Ant or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

@ doesn't mean anything from the Java perspective. However in a DOS .BAT file it indicates that the files contained in the referenced file will be used.

e.g. `DEL @FILENAME.TXT` means that DOS will delete the files listed in `FILENAME.TXT`

I suspect that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: In what shell? Not XP's cmd one at least, and never saw in regular Dos either.

Answer (score 1):

java VM takes options [outlined in this document](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp). I may be wrong but I never see anything what you described. So it could be something to do with shell you are using

Answer (score 0):

Shell expansion is to what you're referring?

```
jvmargs=-Xmx786m -Dfoo=bar
java $jvmargs com.foo.Bar
```

.

```
set jvmargs=-Xms786m -Dfoo.bar
java %jvmargs% com.foo.Bar
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a quite common practice/convention, but I believe you have to implement it yourself (ie. get the filename, open it, read and parse it...).