# What is the @ symbol on the java command which launch a minecraft forge server?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Hi everyone I'm trying to modify my minecraft startup script but I do not understand this line
`java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=50 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=50 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch @libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.19.2-43.2.10/unix_args.txt nogui`

I was expecting to find a .jar file in the java command, the jar which contain the main class and launch the server

I've searched but found nothing about a @ symbol path which replace the .jar file

I read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646889/java-command-line-option-using-symbol) but it is only about setting additional arguments from a file. But the jar file is still mentioned in the command

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#examples-of-using-argument-files-with-paths